# NextAuth.js cross domain

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

How to make an authentication with nextAuth.js that allows to connect my users via a JWT OR session from an external app?

**it's not very clear, let me explain.**

My stack is composed of:

**BACK:** nextJS for API REST and backoffice + nextAuth.js to handle email+google provider (domain.com)

**FRONT:** ReactJS as frontoffice - must use my nextJS API authentication (step 1) BUT not NextAuth.JS (obviously)  (app.domain.com)

**Here's the authentication flow**

1. user browses ***app.domain.com*** (CSR part)
2. user clicks on login (CSR part)
3. user is redirected to ***domain.com/auth/signin*** (SSR part)
4. user completes google authentication
5. user is redirected on ***app.domain.com*** and have access to his
   profile information (back to CSR part)

**Why use ReactJS in addition to nextJS?**

I want to have a separate front and back end, because in the future I'll be adding other web applications to my stack that won't necessarily be in react, or even in JS, so only my api/backoffice will remain monolythic.

I cannot find any ressources other than the one present in the nextAuth documentation but it doesn't really help me because they statement than all your subdomain project are using nextJS